# How to root path loading of CSS in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

The following css loading does not work.
`import style from 'common/style.css'`

JavaScript can be read with root path.
`import Score from 'components/score'`

Could you give me some advice?

Source Tree

```
.
└── src
    ├── app.js
    ├── common
    │   └── style.css
    ├── components
    │   ├── box.js
    │   └── score.js
    └── index.ejs
```

score.js

```
import React from 'react'
import style from 'common/style.css' // <= It is not loaded here

class Score extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div styleName="style.score">25</div>
  }
}

export default Score
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.ejs'
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      "node_modules"
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.css'],
  }
}
```

Error log

```
ERROR in ./src/components/score.js
Module build failed: Error: /Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/src/components/score.js: Cannot find module 'common/style.css'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at getTargetResourcePath (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/dist/index.js:99:20)
    at PluginPass.ImportDeclaration (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/dist/index.js:127:36)
    at newFn (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:276:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:76:18)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:48:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:105:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:103:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:190:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:115:19)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:192:19)
 @ ./src/components/box.js 13:13-40
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js
```

Demo code

https://github.com/yoneapp/webpack-css-load-sample

Comment: change `'common/style.css'` to `'../common/style.css'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Advice from Dwayne Charrington**

This method worked a halfway.

```
ERROR in ./src/components/score.js
Module build failed: Error: /Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/src/components/score.js: Cannot find module 'common/style.css'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at getTargetResourcePath (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/dist/index.js:99:20)
    at PluginPass.ImportDeclaration (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/dist/index.js:127:36)
    at newFn (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:276:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:76:18)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:48:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:105:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:103:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:190:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:115:19)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:192:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/yoneapp/Desktop/webpack-css-load-sample/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
 @ ./src/components/box.js 13:13-31
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js
```

The alias should be success, But, it was failure.
When babel-plugin-react-css-modules was removed, this worked.

It finally became a like this.

score.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from 'common/style.css'
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules'

class Score extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div styleName="score">25</div>
  }
}

export default CSSModules(Score, styles)
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'assets/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.ejs'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common')
    }
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

https://github.com/yoneapp/webpack-css-load-sample/tree/success

Answer (score 2):

Try adding in an alias inside of your `resolve` block which should tell Webpack to resolve all imports from `common/` to `/src/common`:

```
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        alias: {
          common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common/'),
        }
    },
```

Also, you do not need to have `.css` inside of your `extensions` array either. This is only needed for automatically resolving files without an extension, but you probably don't want to do that for styles so you can clearly indicate in your code a stylesheet and a Javascript file.

The other solution of changing your import path will also work, but you'll find once you get more than 3 levels deep, writing `../../../../common/style.css` will get very tiring. Aliases allow you to specify a root level where your imports are resolved, especially great if you have folders for constants, data stores and more in the root of your `src` directory.

If you would like to know more about aliases, the Webpack documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) is a great resource. You can do other things with aliases as well, like exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Given your project structure, I think you are using the wrong path to import the stylesheet to your component.

Try this from inside one of your components:

```js
import style from '../common/style.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add double dot and slash like below

```
import style from '../common/style.css'
import Score from '../components/score'
```